# Airflow Scheduler - Ephemeral Storage - Evicted

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, airflow, amazon-eks

I've been runnning into what should be a simple issue with my airflow scheduler. Every couple of weeks, the scheduler becomes `Evicted`. When I run a describe on the pod, the issue is because `The node was low on resource: ephemeral-storage. Container scheduler was using 14386916Ki, which exceeds its request of 0.`

The question is two fold. First, why is the scheduler utilizing ephemeral-storage? And second, is it possible to do add ephemeral-storage when running on eks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Ephemeral Storage is not Airflow's question but more of the configuration of your K8S cluster.

Assuming we are talking about OpenShift' ephemeral storage:

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/storage/understanding-ephemeral-storage.html

This can be configured in your cluster and it wil make "/var/log" ephemeral.

I think the problem is that `/var/logs` gets full. Possibly some of the system logs (not from airlfow but from some other processes running in the same container). I think a solution will be to have a job that cleans that system log periodically.

For example we have this script that cleans-up Airlfow logs:

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/scripts/in_container/prod/clean-logs.sh

Comment: Thanks Jarek! I think the script might be the way to go. I've deployed this on AWS EKS, and there isn't mention of ephemeral storage / wasn't sure what was consuming it / why i needed it.

I'll give something like that a go! Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any suggestions as to how to run this scrip inside the container? I was thinking an entry point command on the Docker image, but thought I'd ask in case you had a better way.

Comment: separate side-container in the same POD ? Same as we did in our official chart: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/faee841d1b75bfaa7956d43cf65e138fca7b452f/chart/templates/workers/worker-deployment.yaml#L212

Comment: Thanks so much! Your recommendations worked wonderfully.